# Re-installing Windows XP onto Windows 7

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, windows-xp, reinstall

I have an old computer and I wanted to wipe the system clean and install Windows XP Professional onto the computer. The problem is... well, there's a lot.

So first, I went into Disk Management and tried to format the hard drive, but the option wasn't available so I deleted the driver. When I restarted the computer later, I hit the error "`BOOTMGR is missing, Press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to restart`." Solutions online encouraged booting from a USB, so I got a Windows XP Pro ISO file onto a bootable USB drive, and by reordering boot priority in the BIOS, I got through the setup nice and easy.
However, when it asked where I wanted to install Windows XP, only the USB drive appeared. The computer could not find the hard drive (Internet calls it ATAPI CD0). I installed Windows XP onto the USB drive anyways. All the files were successfully copied, but when the computer restarted and booted into USB, the Windows XP logo appeared, quickly followed by an error message: something was corrupted.
Another purported solution was to reorder the BIOS again and put the hard drive first, but naturally, the `BOOTMGR is missing` error came back.The system recovery feature while booting on USB goes to a cmd-like window and doesn't actually clean the system. Besides that, I want to get the Windows XP onto the hard drive and not to boot from the USB.

Does anyone know how to approach this problem?

Comment: XP may need SATA drivers to work on a newer system https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+xp+sata&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-m

Comment: You deleted the driver? It was a serious blunder.

Comment: Make and Model of PC?

Comment: @Moab Lenovo ThinkPad T61, with product key designed for Windows XP Pro, Intel (centrino duo?) Core

Comment: @Mokubai It's an old computer, 2005, designed to run Windows XP

Comment: More than likely the drive did not get made properly, try making it with this tool>>>>>https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56485

Answer (score 0):

Visit This link and see if it helps you. https://www.raymond.cc/blog/install-xp-setup-did-not-find-any-hard-disk-drives-installed-in-your-computer/

Well I would prefer you to use Windows 7 as it is better in system management than XP and one more thing, if you tried to format your "C" drive it's not possible while you are logged on and deleting the driver was a serious mistake.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin I'll take care from next time!